# UITableViewCell selection in editing mode.

Tags: uitableview, swift, event-handling, uikit

I am making a custom UIViewController that I want to show a message when a UITableViewCell is tapped. I create a UITableView and set the property

`tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true`

Even though that property has been set to true, tableView(:didSelectRowAtIndexPath) is not being called to display the message. Why is this and how do I fix it?

Here is my UITableViewController:

```
class GameListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, GameListViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate
{
private var _games: [GameObject] = []

var tableView: UITableView {return (view as GameListView).tableView}
var gameListView: GameListView {return (view as GameListView) }

override func loadView()
{
    view =  GameListView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    gameListView.delegate = self
}

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return _games.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var index: Int = indexPath.row         
    let currentGame = _games[index]

    var cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
    cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByCharWrapping
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 2

    if currentGame.isFinished == true
    {
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Finished.png")
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Winner: Player\(currentGame.playerMakingMove)\nMissiles Launched: \(currentGame.missileCount)"
    }
    else
    {
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Resume.png")
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Turn: Player\(currentGame.playerMakingMove)\nMissiles Launched: \(currentGame.missileCount)"
    }
    return cell
}

/*Handles deleting the cells*/
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete)
    {
        var index: Int = indexPath.row
        _games.removeAtIndex(index)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(array: [indexPath]), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Left)
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}

/* Performs when a cell is touched */
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    var index: Int = indexPath.row
    tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)

    println("inside tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath")
    var message = UIAlertView(title: "Row selected", message: "You have selected a row", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Click ME!", otherButtonTitles: "no other buttons")

    message.show()
}

func makeNewGame()
{
    addGames(1)
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func addGames(gameNumber: Int)
{
    var p1 = Player()
    var p2 = Player()

    for var i = 0; i < gameNumber; i++
    {
        var randBool = Bool( round(drand48()))  // True/False
        var randPlayer:Int = Int( round( (drand48() + 1)) ) // 1 or 2
        var randMissleCount:Int = Int( arc4random_uniform(5000) + 1 )    //1 - 5001

        _games.append(GameObject(isFinished: randBool, playerMakingMove: randPlayer, missileCount: randMissleCount, player1: p1, player2: p2))
    }

}
```

}

Here is my UIView that contains the UITableView:

```
protocol GameListViewDelegate: class
{
func makeNewGame()
}

class GameListView: UIView, PictureButtonDelegate
{
var newGameButton: PictureButton!
var tableView: UITableView!

weak var delegate: GameListViewDelegate? = nil

override init(frame: CGRect)
{
    super.init(frame: frame)

    newGameButton = PictureButton(frame: CGRect(), fileName: "NewGame.png")
    newGameButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    newGameButton.delegate = self
    newGameButton.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)


    tableView = UITableView()
    tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true
    tableView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    self.addSubview(newGameButton)
    self.addSubview(tableView)
}

override func layoutSubviews()
{
    let views: [String : UIView] = ["button": newGameButton, "tableView": tableView]

    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[button]-|", options: .allZeros, metrics: nil, views: views))

    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[tableView]-|", options: .allZeros, metrics: nil, views: views))

    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-(>=15,<=25)-[button]-[tableView]-|", options: .allZeros, metrics: nil, views: views))
}

func buttonPushed()
{
    delegate?.makeNewGame()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

Comment: show only necessary code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a delegate for the `UITableView` and implement `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`.

You only set the dataSource, but never the delegate (only a `GameListViewDelegate` for `GameListView`).

Change your `viewDidLoad` function in `GameListViewController` to:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
}
```